# Trouble when assign dynamic space to string array?

Tags: c++

I am new to C programing. I tried to get the following code work but fails.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

  string* ps = (string*) malloc(9*sizeof(string));
  ps[0] = "jasdhk";
  ps[1] ="rty";
  ps[2] = "tyu";
  return 0;
}
```

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: This is *c++* and *not* c.

Comment: For one thing, this is a really nasty mix of C and C++. That said, let's suppose this really is what you wanted to do. How is it failing? The real answer is of course, for dynamic arrays in C++, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: use `vector` instead of.

Comment: @BoBTFish: It is C-syle C++, but not a mix (that would imply it compiles with a C compiler).

Comment: Learn [ask] and take the [tour]. Then learn which language you are actually using. C and C++ are **different** languages!

Comment: @Olaf Is `<stdlib.h>` guaranteed to be present in C++? I thought not. Making it not quite C++, definitely not C.

Comment: @BoBTFish: You can use C libraries in C++ if they are augmented properly (`extern "C" ...`. Anyway, I think we agree this is rubbish code.

Comment: or `string* ps = new string[9];` instead of.

Comment: You need to get yourself either a [C book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or a [C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), depending on which language you're actually going to learn.

Answer (score 4):

The code is actually a hybrid of C and C++, and is not valid in either language.

The usage of C++ headers (`iostream`, `string`, and `stack`) is not valid in C.  Similarly, `using namespace std` is C++, not C.

The usage of C's `malloc()` to allocate a C++ type with constructor is invalid, since C library functions do not invoke constructors for C++ objects.  `std::string` (which is what the name `string` resolves to, thanks to usage of `<string>` and `using namespace std` in this case) is a (`typedef` for a specialiation of a) C++ template class with a constructor.

Either abandon `malloc()` and use operator `new` to dynamically allocate C++ objects or, better, use `std::vector<std::string>` to dynamically manage a collection of `std::string`.

Comment: Using `malloc` in C++ is just deprecated, but still allowed.

Comment: Read carefully. I didn't say `malloc()` can't be used in C++.   I explained why it is invalid in the code in the original question.

Comment: It would be less ambivalent when started with "This usage ...", but ok.